# Voice-Pressing keys in Dragon NaturallySpeaking: which symbol can it types?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking, one can type symbols with the voice command `press [symbol name]`. For example, `press t`, `press dollar sign`, or `press F5`. Where can I get the list of all symbols / keys that can be typed with the `press` voice command?

Comment: Look in "Commands List Appendix" in your manual.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, which one you are you referring to? I looked at [Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12's Installation and User Guide](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/dragon/product-resources/user-documentation/index.htm) but I didn't find it.

Comment: I was looking here http://www.manualslib.com/manual/239984/Sony-Icd-Bp150vtp-Dragon-Naturally-Speaking-7.html?page=186#manual

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, it doesn't look exhaustive but that's a good start, you're welcome to post it as an answer (I can take care of adding screenshots of the tables).

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on  [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)'s comment:

Old versions of the Dragon NaturallySpeaking's user guide has a (incomplete) list.

From the [Dragon NaturallySpeaking 7's user guide](http://support.nuance.com/usersguides/?UsersGuidesProduct=naturallyspeaking):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]